# Is it possible to enable a privilege by default?

Tags: c++, winapi, privileges

I'm trying to create a program that will allow managing privileges. But unfortunately, I can't achieve the result I want. I think I'm missing something.

I was trying to enable a privilege by default using code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--)
and setting `Attributes` to `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` or `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT | SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`. The attributes of a privilege can be a combination of the following values:

```
SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT (0x00000001L)
SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED            (0x00000002L)
SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED            (0X00000004L)
SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS    (0x80000000L)
```

I checked the user's privileges using `whoami /priv` in cmd and I also retrieved information about privileges using function `GetTokenInformation`, and I compared the results and found out that `Attributes` of enabled privileges is 3 (which is `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT | SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`).

I tried to set `Attributes` to 3 then I checked privileges' information using `GetTokenInformation` again, but `Attributes` of the privilege was set to 2. I also tried `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` and checked again, but `Attributes` was set to 0.

So these are my questions:

1. Why does 3 turn into 2 and 1 turn into 0? Is it possible to set a privilege's `Attribute` to 3 or 1? In other words, can I do something to be able to use `whoami /priv` and see that there are privileges enabled that weren't enabled before?
2. Is it possible to add more privileges to an account? I tried to do that using secpol.msc and `LsaAddAccountRights` function, but the number of privileges is the same.

Additional question:

3. After a lot of searching I found this [article](https://medium.com/@markmotig/enable-all-token-privileges-a7d21b1a4a77) about enabling privileges using a powershell script. How come a c# code doesn't work, but the same code wrapped in a powershell script does the job?

I'd be so grateful if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks and me sorry for me english.

Comment: _How come a c# code doesn't work_ Hard to tell, without seeing it...

Comment: @PaulSanders here's the [link](https://github.com/fashionproof/EnableAllTokenPrivs). It was at the bottom of the article

Comment: Links rot.  All relevant code (and error messages) should be included in the question (as text, not images), please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**question1:**

According to the Doc:[AdjustTokenPrivileges function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-adjusttokenprivileges)

> [in, optional] NewState
>
> A pointer to a TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure that specifies an array of
> privileges and their attributes. If the DisableAllPrivileges parameter
> is FALSE, the AdjustTokenPrivileges function enables, disables, or
> removes these privileges for the token.

As far as I'm concerned, the value of `tp.Privileges[0].Attributes` is `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` or `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED`or `None`.

**question2:**

You can assign privileges to accounts either by using the Local Security Policy Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (Secpol.msc) or by calling the `LsaAddAccountRights function`.

In my opinion, you could assign privileges to accounts, you couldn't add more privileges to an account.

According to the Doc: [Changing Privileges in a Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/changing-privileges-in-a-token)

> You can change the privileges in either a primary or an impersonation
> token in two ways:
>
> Enable or disable privileges by using the `AdjustTokenPrivileges function`.
>
> Restrict or remove privileges by using the `CreateRestrictedToken function`.

**question3:**

Could you please provide the sample to help us reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Question 3 was stupid, so never mind.